# Nextflow: Can I parameterize similar processes inside a for loop?

Tags: nextflow

I have set of ~5 processes which perform very similar tasks such that their differences can be parameterized. Rather than putting 5 items through some channel (which seems complicated), or defining 5 separate processes, it appears to be possible in Nextflow to declare the processes in a for loop, and output into an array of channels.

Below is a prototypical example and it seems to work as intended. (I understand this could be done differently with some channel cross product operator but I am just giving this as an example of a process in a for loop.)

Is there anything wrong with doing this? Is there a better way to do it?

Bonus question - the name of the process below is "foo". I would like to have the index reflected in the name i.e. "foo_$i" but this doesn't seem possible by default - any way to do this??

```
some_inputs = ['prot','dna', 'rna']

some_parameters = [5,3,2,7,1]

// Set up an array of channels to output to
receivers = new ArrayList<Channel>()
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    receivers.add(Channel.create())
}

// Iterate 5 times to create 5 processes each with different parameters
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    // WOW - process can be defined inside a for loop!!
    process "foo" {

      // Extract parameters here so correct $i value is used
      p = some_parameters[i]

      input:
      val x from Channel.from(some_inputs)

      output:
      val "$x $p" into receivers[i] // Note that correct index $i seems to be used here

      """
      """
    }
}

// Confirm that each of the processes outputted independently with the correct parameter
receivers[0].view { "Received[0]: $it" }
receivers[1].view { "Received[1]: $it" }
receivers[2].view { "Received[2]: $it" }
receivers[3].view { "Received[3]: $it" }
receivers[4].view { "Received[4]: $it" }
```

Output - note that the parameter is consistent within each input channel i.e. working correctly:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `play.nf` [fabulous_keller] - revision: c89e2b2281
executor >  local (15)
[10/b477ec] process > foo (3) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[16/8282ba] process > foo (2) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[db/f7327e] process > foo (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[fb/886f6f] process > foo (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[46/c34ed3] process > foo (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
Received[1]: rna 3
Received[1]: prot 3
Received[4]: rna 1
Received[2]: rna 2
Received[0]: dna 5
Received[2]: dna 2
Received[2]: prot 2
Received[0]: prot 5
Received[3]: rna 7
Received[0]: rna 5
Received[1]: dna 3
Received[3]: dna 7
Received[4]: dna 1
Received[3]: prot 7
Received[4]: prot 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use channels, this is what nextflow's entire design is based on. I'm honestly surprised that spawning 5 processes with the same name in a loop even works.

Turn your parameters into regular channels, use the `combine` operator (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) to transform the 2 parameter channels into a channel that has each combination of params/inputs. Feed this channel into the  `foo`  process. Afterward use `branch` (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) to split your `foo` output channel into 5 different channels.

````
typechan = Channel.from(5,3,2,7,1)
numchan = Channel.from('prot','dna', 'rna')

cartesian = numchan.combine(typechan)

process foo {
  input:
  val numtype from cartesian
  output:
  val numtype into bar 
  script:
  """
  echo $numtype
  """
}

bar.branch {
  one: it[1] == 1
  two: it[1] == 2
  three: it[1] == 3 
  five: it[1] == 5
  seven : it[1] == 7
}.set {result}
result.one.view()
```
````

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create processes in a loop when you have channels. The [each qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-repeaters) allows you to repeat the execution of a process for each item in a collection. For example, the contents of 'test.nf':

```
some_inputs = Channel.of( 'prot', 'dna', 'rna' )
some_parameters = Channel.of( 5, 3, 2, 7, 1 )

process foo {

    tag { "task: ${task.index} - ${x},${y}" }

    input:
    val x from some_inputs
    each y from some_parameters

    output:
    tuple val(x), val(y) into receivers

    """
    echo "x: ${x}; y: ${y}"
    """
}

results = receivers.branch { x, y ->
    
    five: y == 5
        return tuple( x, y )

    three: y == 3
        return tuple( x, y )

    two: y == 2
        return tuple( x, y )

    seven: y == 7
        return tuple( x, y )
    
    one: y == 1
        return tuple( x, y )
}

results.five.view { "My result for param 5 is: $it" }
results.three.view { "My result for param 3 is: $it" }
results.two.view { "My result for param 2 is: $it" }
results.seven.view { "My result for param 7 is: $it" }
results.one.view { "My result for param 1 is: $it" }
```

Then running like:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false test.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [fabulous_franklin] - revision: 14c3290d2b
[6e/c12ce7] Submitted process > foo (task: 7 - dna,3)
[93/616f93] Submitted process > foo (task: 4 - prot,7)
[27/0bc3c4] Submitted process > foo (task: 3 - prot,2)
[0d/0d0b51] Submitted process > foo (task: 9 - dna,7)
[d4/f56d18] Submitted process > foo (task: 6 - dna,5)
[b0/d1535f] Submitted process > foo (task: 8 - dna,2)
[13/0a660a] Submitted process > foo (task: 5 - prot,1)
[f0/1c2f57] Submitted process > foo (task: 2 - prot,3)
[3f/3e893d] Submitted process > foo (task: 1 - prot,5)
[19/2921de] Submitted process > foo (task: 10 - dna,1)
My result for param 3 is: [dna, 3]
My result for param 7 is: [prot, 7]
My result for param 7 is: [dna, 7]
[a7/953a2b] Submitted process > foo (task: 11 - rna,3)
[1c/0fd4ef] Submitted process > foo (task: 12 - rna,5)
My result for param 1 is: [prot, 1]
[39/d21adf] Submitted process > foo (task: 14 - rna,7)
My result for param 5 is: [dna, 5]
My result for param 2 is: [prot, 2]
My result for param 2 is: [dna, 2]
[f6/8509a7] Submitted process > foo (task: 15 - rna,1)
My result for param 5 is: [prot, 5]
[6f/cee0ae] Submitted process > foo (task: 13 - rna,2)
My result for param 3 is: [rna, 3]
My result for param 1 is: [dna, 1]
My result for param 2 is: [rna, 2]
My result for param 3 is: [prot, 3]
My result for param 1 is: [rna, 1]
My result for param 5 is: [rna, 5]
My result for param 7 is: [rna, 7]
```

The answer to your bonus question is to use the `task.index` variable in your script. I used this to [tag](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#tag) your job, but it can be used anywhere in the process declaration. You likely won't need this variable though.

Usually, using the [branch operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) is enough for most use cases. However,it's possible to implement your own branching function. The following uses the new DSL, DSL2, to automatically fork the 'receivers' channel:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process foo {

    tag { "task: ${task.index} - ${x},${y}" }

    input:
    val x
    each y

    output:
    tuple val(x), val(y)

    """
    echo "x: ${x}; y: ${y}"
    """
}

def branchByElement( input_ch, elements, by=0 ) {

    def targets = [:]
    for( element in elements ) {
        def key = element
        targets[ key ] = { input_ch.filter { it[by] == key } }
    }
    return targets
}

workflow {

    some_inputs = [ 'prot', 'dna', 'rna' ]
    some_parameters = [ 5, 3, 2, 7, 1 ]

    inputs_ch = Channel.fromList( some_inputs )
    parameters_ch = Channel.fromList( some_parameters )

    foo( inputs_ch, parameters_ch )

    parameter_results = branchByElement( foo.out, some_parameters, by=1 )
    input_results = branchByElement( foo.out, some_inputs, by=0 )

    parameter_results[7].call().view { "Param 7: $it" }
    input_results.dna().view { "Input dna: $it" }
}
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [distraught_meninsky] - revision: 04df251752
[bb/32325f] Submitted process > foo (task: 4 - prot,7)
[a0/19fdf5] Submitted process > foo (task: 8 - dna,2)
[e9/4c1d09] Submitted process > foo (task: 6 - dna,5)
[a3/dcb002] Submitted process > foo (task: 2 - prot,3)
[db/7e612e] Submitted process > foo (task: 5 - prot,1)
[cd/dfa84e] Submitted process > foo (task: 9 - dna,7)
[d4/6a85f2] Submitted process > foo (task: 7 - dna,3)
[f0/8e8bf4] Submitted process > foo (task: 1 - prot,5)
[89/f20a28] Submitted process > foo (task: 3 - prot,2)
Input dna: [dna, 2]
Param 7: [prot, 7]
Input dna: [dna, 5]
[53/056fe4] Submitted process > foo (task: 10 - dna,1)
[f3/a61abf] Submitted process > foo (task: 12 - rna,3)
Input dna: [dna, 7]
[f9/a568a8] Submitted process > foo (task: 13 - rna,2)
Param 7: [dna, 7]
[06/72bb6c] Submitted process > foo (task: 11 - rna,5)
Input dna: [dna, 3]
[a3/6d80d8] Submitted process > foo (task: 14 - rna,7)
[ac/acdb5a] Submitted process > foo (task: 15 - rna,1)
Param 7: [rna, 7]
Input dna: [dna, 1]
```

Comment: I think `each` is even more elegant than combine, do you also have a more elegant way to split the resulting channel than `branch` ?

Comment: @Pallie I think there is using a function and the new DSL2 - please see my update above.